# How do I interpret or otherwise evaluate Rust at runtime?

Tags: rust, interpreter

I've been searching, and while this seems to be a much-wanted feature, all search results seem to be at least one year old.

What is the current state of this? Is there a good solution to evaluating arbitrary Rust code at runtime (like Haskell's [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint))?

Maybe something can be done with [Miri](https://github.com/solson/miri)?

Comment: "a much-wanted feature", really? Who wants that? Why do *you* want that? Miri serves a completely different purpose. I'm afraid you should not try to pursue this goal. You wouldn't want to interpret C or C++ would you?

Comment: Well if you do google, you will find quite a few people who have been asking for this, and it does exist in many other languages, too. 

I cannot tell you why others want that, it does seem a bit weird doesn't it. My use case is very much an edge-case, but I would like to be able to send any sort of rust code to a server and execute it at runtime, that is my use-case.

Comment: Many (most?) of the popular languages that support "eval" are interpreted languages. Most compiled languages either do not offer support for eval at all or via a vastly more complicated api than simply `eval(string)`.

Comment: Well both scala and haskell offer this, and I'm sure there is more - but they both also have a REPL.

Answer (score 5):

[Miri](https://github.com/solson/miri) (short for **MIR** **I**nterpreter) is the de-facto interpreter of Rust code. It is what powers the compile-time function evaluation inside of rustc, the Rust compiler, but Miri is more featureful than what is currently used by compiler.

For experimentation purposes, Miri is also available in the Rust playground. It can be used to evaluate a particular run of a program, detecting if certain types of undefined behavior exist.

Miri does **not** provide a Rust REPL, but it may be [part of creating such a tool](https://github.com/solson/miri/issues/511).

Comment: I thought rust didn't really have a CTFE? Or does it? I looked into Miri, but this seems really a very hacky solution. I can also just call rustc from rust itself, isn't there something a little cleaner?

Comment: @jundl77 CTFE is still nascent, certainly. Certain abilities are available (for example, [`AtomicUsize::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.new) is a `const fn`) and others are not.